# Is there a cleaner way to conditionally 'last' out of this Perl loop?

Tags: perl, syntactic-sugar

Not really knowing Perl, I have been enhancing a Perl script with help from a friendly search engine.

I find that I need to break out of a loop while setting a flag if a condition comes true:

```
foreach my $element (@array) {
    if($costlyCondition) {
        $flag = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

I know that the nicer way to use 'last' is something like this:

```
foreach my $element (@array) {
    last if ($costlyCondition);
}
```

Of course, this means that while I can enjoy the syntactic sugar, I cannot set my flag inside the loop, which means I need to evaluate `$costlyCondition` once again outside.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: postfix `if` really only is for one statement. Your first is preferable for multiple statements on one conditional.

Comment: I think an if block is the better option in this case. The usual argument for postfix conditionals on loop controls is that it places the more significant code to the left. Emphasizing that the loop has multiple exit conditions over what those exit conditions are. In this case if you use some of the compound expressions suggested the result just buries the loop control deeper in the expression making it harder to see at a glance.

Comment: @Joel: You are right. I stay with the original version.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use a `do {...}` block:

```
do {$flag = 1; last} if $costlyCondition
```

---

you can use the `,` operator to join the statements:

```
$flag = 1, last if $costlyCondition;
```

---

you can do the same with the logical `&&` operator:

```
(($flag = 1) && last) if $costlyCondition;
```

or even the lower priority `and`:

```
(($flag = 1) and last) if $costlyCondition;
```

---

at the end of the day, there's no real reason to do any of these.  They all do exactly the same as your original code.  If your original code works and is legible, leave it like it is.

Comment: Add `$flag = 1 and last if $costlyCondition;` to your tool-shelf.

Comment: in your second example, drop the {}.  They aren't needed.

Comment: I learn't a new perl construct! (do). Thanks! And like you and almost everyone said, it is best to keep the code as it is.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Nathan, that while neat looking code is neat, sometimes a readable version is better. Just for the hell of it, though, here's a horrible version:

```
last if $flag = $costly_condition;
```

Note the use of assignment `=` instead of equality `==`. The assignment will return whatever value is in `$costly_condition`.

This of course will not make `$flag = 1`, but whatever `$costly_condition` is. But, since that needs to be true, so will `$flag`. To remedy that, you can - as Zaid mentioned in the comments - use:

```
last if $flag = !! $costly_condition;
```

As mentioned, pretty horrible solutions, but they do work.

Comment: `last if $flag = !! $costly_condition;` would do the trick ;)

Comment: @zaid Hehe, yeah, I saw that one too.

Comment: to make it even worse: `last unless $flag = ! $costly_condition` ;)

Comment: @pavel That would set `$flag` to false, though. =P

Comment: @TLP: you're right; so the program logic has to be reversed to... making it even nastier...

Answer (score 5):

One thought is to do the loop in a subroutine that returns different values depending on the exit point.

```
my $flag = check_elements(\@array);

# later...

sub check_elements {
  my $arrayref = shift;
  for my $ele (@$arrayref) {
    return 1 if $costly_condition;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but highly not recommended: such tricks decrease readability of your code.

```
foreach my $element (@array) {
    $flag = 1 and last if $costlyCondition;
}
```